# How to rotate grid using package sf in R?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

**CONTEXT**

From xy points I create plots using st_buffer and st_make_grid (as shown below in the code).
With these plots, I want to create grids. Once the grids are created, I want to rotate them to an specific angle. In this final step is where I get the error:

```
Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) : 
  polygons not (all) closed
```

**CODE OF EXAMPLE**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(spatialEco)

xy <- st_as_sf(data.frame(x = 1,
                          y = 3),
               coords = c("x", "y"))
plot(xy)

# 1) Buffer
cen_buffer = st_buffer(xy, 100)

ggplot()  +
  geom_sf(data= cen_buffer$geometry, color='black') +
  geom_sf(data = xy$geometry, color = 'red')


# 2) Square
square_1ha <- st_make_grid(cen_buffer, n=1)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=cen_buffer, color='black') +
  geom_sf(data=square_1ha, color='black', fill=NA) +
  geom_sf(data = xy$geometry, color = 'red')

# 3) Grid

grid_spacing <- 10

grid_1ha <- st_make_grid(square_1ha, square = T, cellsize = c(grid_spacing, grid_spacing)) %>%
  st_sf()
grid_1ha <- sf::st_set_precision(grid_1ha, 1000000) %>% sf::st_make_valid()

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = grid_1ha$geometry, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data=cen_buffer, color='black') +
  geom_sf(data=square_1ha, color='black', fill=NA) +
  geom_sf(data = xy$geometry, color = 'red')

# 4) Rotate
grid_1ha <- rotate.polygon(grid_1ha, angle = 45)
```

**APPROACHES I TRIED**

Using st_union(grid) works, and the polygon rotates. However, this does not solve the problem, since the inner grid would be gone.

I tried to use this `grid_1ha <- sf::st_set_precision(grid_1ha, 1000000) %>% sf::st_make_valid()` since, based on other stackoverflow questions, could solve the problem. In my case this did not work.

I tried to transform the grid to MULTIPOLYGON using `st_cast()`but with no success.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the entire grid about the centre (0,0)? Because rotate.polygon doesn't do that. It rotates a single feature about its centroid or a corner. It would take a lot of faffing to make it rotate a set of features like you have in your grid....

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would like to rotate the entire grid. By transforming the polygon to MULTIPOLYGON, I tried that rotate.polygon understands the polygon as a whole and not as a polygon composed by single features, but that had no success. Do you may know other functions or ways to rotate the whole grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication on `sfc` objects; from your example, try

```
m = matrix(c(.9,.1,-.1,.9), 2)
st_geometry(grid_1ha) * m -> m2
plot(m2)
```

and see help and examples for ?Ops.sfc
[image]

Comment: for `m` you need to use a proper rotation matrix.